# Why is my buffer hold the same data after multiple read()s?

Tags: c++, synchronization, client-server, named-pipes

I have a client/server program in C using named pipes. My server is supposed to send the message `"last line"` to let the client know that the last line is coming, because that line has to be output specially. My client reads in "last line" and is supposed to then get what the last line actually is, but after the next `read()`, my buffer still holds "last line".

**Edit** As requested here is my server and client code where the read/writes are happening. The overall goal of my program is to send a filename and search term to the server which reads the file line by line and returns the frequency the term was found on each line. That information is then printed by the client. After reading the whole file, the server is to send a grand total, which the client prints specially formatted. The server ends "server-EOF" to indicate it is finished communicating. This is a HW assignment, so those are the specifications I have given.

Server:

```
 ifstream rf(requestedFileName)

        size_t found;
        getline(rf,tempLine);//gets the first line of the file
        while (!rf.eof())
        {       
                currentLineNumber++;

                found= tempLine.find(requestedTarget);//searches line for target
                while(found != string::npos)//if it was found, increase counts and search again
                {
                        totalTimesFoundInFile++;
                        totalTimesFoundOnLine++;
                        found=tempLine.find(requestedTarget, found+1);
                }
 if(totalTimesFoundOnLine != 0) //If it was found create the right string and send it to client
                {
                        int n = sprintf(stringToSend, "Appeared on Line %d,     %d times",currentLineNumber,
                                        totalTimesFoundOnLine);
                        write(fd2, stringToSend, sizeof(stringToSend));
                }

                getline(rf,tempLine);//gets the next line
                totalTimesFoundOnLine = 0; //resets the found count

        }

        //create the special total string. 
        int t = sprintf(stringToSend, "Appeared a Total of %d Times",totalTimesFoundInFile);
        //Send a message to the client to let it know the special total line is coming
        char finalLine[] = "final line";
        if(write(fd2, finalLine, sizeof(finalLine)) != sizeof(finalLine))
        {
                cout<<"error writing" <<endl; }

        cout <<"Just put 'finalLine' into pipe" <<endl;//lets me know the signal went out

        int s= write(fd2,stringToSend, t);//writes the special total line into the pipe
        if(s != t)
                cout <<"error writing" <<endl;

        cout <<"Just put last line into pipe" <<endl;//verifies that the special line got into the pipe and didn't block

        char endingMessage[]="Server-EOF";//Let the client know the server is finished
        write(fd2, endingMessage, sizeof(endingMessage));
        cout <<"Wrote endingMessage" <<endl; //verifies the message got sent
```

Client:

```
char endMessage[] = "Server-EOF";
int nread;

nread = read(fd2, buffer, maxBufferSize);//reads the first input from the pipe
if(nread == -1) cout << "a read error occurred" <<endl;
else{
        while(strcmp(buffer, endMessage) != 0)  //check to 'server-EOF' message
        {
                cout << "Size of buffer is: " << strlen(buffer) <<endl;//verifies size of message recieved
                if(strcmp(buffer, "final line") == 0)
                {//Handler to recieve special total message and output it
                        nread =read(fd2, buffer, maxBufferSize);//get total message
                        if(nread == -1)
                        {
                                cout <<"a read error occurred" <<endl;
                                break;
                        }
                        else{
                                cout <<"Size of buffer is: " <<strlen(buffer) <<endl;//verify it got the total message
                                cout<< "Client : PID" << clientPID << " - Target >>"
                                        << requestedTarget <<"<< in File >>" << requestedFileName
                                        <<"<< " << buffer << endl;
                                }
                }
                else{//Print out the information about search numbers for regular liens
                        cout <<"Client : PID " << clientPID << " - Target >>"
                                <<requestedTarget <<"<< " << buffer <<endl;
                    }
                nread=read(fd2, buffer, maxBufferSize);//reads next message from pipe
                if(nread == -1)
 {
                        cout << "a read error occurred" << endl;
                        break;
                }
        }
        }
```

output:

```
Final string to send: Appeared a Total of 4 Times
Just put 'finalLine' into pipe
Just put last line into pipe
Wrote endingMessage
Size of buffer is: 27
Client : PID 5172 - Target >>apple<< Appeared on Line 1,       1 times
Size of buffer is: 27
Client : PID 5172 - Target >>apple<< Appeared on Line 2,       1 times
Size of buffer is: 27
Client : PID 5172 - Target >>apple<< Appeared on Line 4,       2 times
Size of buffer is: 10
Size of buffer is: 10
Client : PID6144 - Target >>apple<< in File >>pipedTest.txt<< final line
//This line ^^ should say something like" appeared a total of 11 times" instead of "final line"
```

It appears that my client is getting the message "final line" (10 characters), but when it is supposed to read the total line after that it apparently still have only has "final line" in the buffer. I know this because later output is just an endless loop with "final line" as my buffer. That loop must mean that all of my further `read()` calls are all returning a buffer with "final line" in it

Comment: I don't think waiting until it is empty is going to solve the problem. Pipes should be guaranteeing in-order delivery of data, so that is not a concern. Please show the code where you read and write from these pipes. Note that it may be necessary to flush the pipe on the server side; perhaps the data is just being buffered by the OS and you need to indicate that the data should be flushed in order to ensure it gets delivered.

Comment: @cdhowie  I added it as requested. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

A pipe is a stream of bytes. You can't change that. You need to fix the client to correctly find the ends of messages. If you have a stream of bytes but need a stream of messages, then you need to implement a message layer.

Here's some broken code:

```
nread = read(fd2, buffer, maxBufferSize);//reads the first input from the pipe
if(nread == -1) cout << "a read error occurred" <<endl;
else{
        while(strcmp(buffer, endMessage) != 0)  //check to 'server-EOF' message
```

The `strcmp` function is only for C-style strings, not for arbitrary data. The `nread` variable holds the length of the data you read, but you process the data completely ignoring it. That can't possibly work.

Comment: How could I do that? Doesn't read() automatically stop at the end of each transmission, aka \0?

Comment: @GabrielleLee No, it doesn't. There isn't an "each transmission", there's a stream of bytes. The `read` function gives you some arbitrary number of bytes, up to the number you asked for. If you didn't get the whole message, you can call `read` again.

Comment: So how does the read() ever know how much to grab out of the pipe? Does it just grab all my buffer can handle?

Comment: It grabs as much as it can, up to the limit you specify. It's your job to figure out whether that consists of one or more complete messages since you are implementing messages.

Comment: So in reference to your main answer, how should I be checking that the buffer isn't holding "server-EOF" if i can't use `strcmp`? I also don't think that's really my issue, though I could easily be wrong

Comment: I don't know what "server-EOF" is. How does your message protocol mark the end of a message?

Comment: That is what the value of `endMessage` is in my`strcmp` call. Its the message that my server is to send when its all done.

Comment: If you have [memmem](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmem), you can use it. If not, just write a function to use `memchr` to find each instance of the first character in the returned data and then `memcmp` to see if the rest of the message is there. Do not use `str*` functions on arbitrary chunks of bytes -- they're for C-style strings only.

Comment: So you're saying I should just check my buffer for the substring "server-EOF"? What if its in the middle or near the end? Wouldn't that cause anything before it to be ignored?

Comment: @GabrielleLee Once you've found it, you need to correctly handle everything in the buffer before it and after it.

Comment: Alright,that makes sense considering memmem returns the start of the substring. Thanks for taking your time with this

Answer (score 0):

The data is guaranteed to be in order but even a short message might arrive in chunks. You can try closing the pipe and then opening a new one if you want it fresh. Or you can add some sort of termination to indicate the end of each transmission. The code that receives the information will have to be adding incoming data to a buffer and then be able to find the end (which can indicate the start of the next message).